# In Rxjs is it an anti-pattern if you add a value to an array, and then immediately after emit that array as an observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my angular application, I want user to be able to upload few images and then I want to display their preview using subjects and observables.

My component.ts file has these properties:

```
uploadPicturesSubject$: Subject<any[]> = new Subject<any[]>();
  previewUrls$: Observable<any[]> = this.uploadPicturesSubject$.asObservable();
  previewUrls: any[] = [];
```

Then in my event handler for the (change) event (when user uploads photos) I have the following code:

```
...
const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(uploadPicture.file);
      reader.onload = (event: any) => {        
        this.previewUrls.push(event.target.result)
        this.uploadPicturesSubject$.next(this.previewUrls);
      };
```

In my template I use the async pipe to subscribe the the previewUrls$ observable and everything works as expected. I wasn't sure if adding the src of the uploaded image with the line `this.previewUrls.push(event.target.result)` and then emitting the array `this.uploadPicturesSubject$.next(this.previewUrls);` was an anti-pattern or not because it felt like there was more code doing it this way, rather than simply in the html template doing an `*ngFor` loop on the `this.previewUrls` array as it achieves the same result.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: FYI: `onload` can trigger **after** the component has been destroyed.

Comment: what do you recommend?

Comment: I would keep a reference to all of the `FileReader` objects you create, and then call `reader.abort()` in the `OnDestroy` hook for the component.

Comment: I see to prevent the event from completing or executing while the component is no longer in the dom, right?

Comment: Right, it might never happen depending on how you use the component, but it's always good to clean up a component when it's destroyed. Otherwise you'll be trying to figure out why you've got errors in the console log at some random time in the future.

Comment: perfect. Thanks for that tip also, this would apply to any native event right? Any event may complete after component is destroy?

Comment: Any kind of callback that is handled inside the component's source code. This doesn't include template binding like `<img (load)="myFunc()">` since the DOM element is destroyed with the component. Things like `.subscribe()` on observables or `addEventListener()` are trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, mixing reactive patterns (subjects, observables) with other patterns where state is stored in local variables seems like an anti-pattern.

To prevent this, I'd take a different approach:

I'd start with just an uploadPicture subject (would be great to get some typing in to avoid 'any'). The idea here is only one picture ever goes into it at a time.

```
uploadPicture = new Subject<any>();
```

Then I'd set up another observable that hooks into this uploadPicture subject:

```
previewUrls$ = uploadPicture.pipe(
    scan((pictures, newPicture) => pictures.concat(newPicture), [])
)
```

What's great about scan is it emits every time a value comes through. To me (and a recent tweet by Ben Lesh confirmed this), it is one of the most powerful operators in RxJS.

So any time a new picture comes in, you just next on the uploadPicture subject:

`this.uploadPicture.next(event.target.result)`

and the whole array including the new picture will emit from previewUrls$.

From here, you should just be able to async pipe `previewUrls$` and get the same result.

Comment: Thank you so much! It did not feel right at all what I was doing and given 110+ rxjs operators I knew there was a better way to handle it. I never came across scan. It appears to maintain the initial array values in memory fantastic!

Comment: I was fortunate enough to see this talk in person https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XKfhGntZROQ by Michael Hladky (the text is nearly unreadable in the video I'm sorry) and there he introduced me to the power of the scan operator.

Comment: I saw a lot of the ngConf videos, but this one I have not yet seen. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Now, do you know if its possible to remove items from that internal accumulator stored inside of the scan operator?

Comment: Good question and I think you hit the limit of the operator there :). I ran into this limitation when I tried to make an "undo" button... One idea is another subject ```removePicture``` and then do a merge(uploadPicture, removePicture) instead of just uploadPicture... but then you'd have to get creative on your array handling inside the scan. Might be worth a separate SO post, as I'm also curious if there's a good way to handle such a situation.

Comment: Yes, my exact scenario. I just asked that question here. Let me know if you would add any modifications to the post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56309545/in-rxjs-scan-operator-is-it-possible-to-remove-an-item-from-the-internal-accumu