# In Rxjs scan operator, is it possible to remove an item from the internal accumulator created by the scan operator?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Based on this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56309242/in-rxjs-is-it-an-anti-pattern-if-you-add-a-value-to-an-array-and-then-immediate/56309329?noredirect=1#comment99229102_56309329), I am using the Rxjs scan operator to keep track of all of the observables that get emitted in an the accumulator array, and then each new incoming value I am adding it to that internal accumulator array created by the scan operator and then I am emitting the single array. This allows me to bind to that array observable with the async pipe in the template and display previews of images user uploaded. However if I want to implement the remove or undo functionality, I have need access to that array to be able to remove an item from it.

This is my scan operator:

```
uploadPicture: Subject<UploadPicture> = new Subject<UploadPicture>();
  previewPictures$ = this.uploadPicture.pipe(
    scan(
      (pictures, newPicture) => [...pictures, newPicture],
      new Array<UploadPicture>()
    )
  );
```

Now when user clicks undo or remove on a picture, I want to take that value out of the array and update the view. Any ideas how this can be achieved?

`

Comment: My guess is that ```scan``` isn't our answer here. I have some ideas, but they're pretty messy, which kind of defeats the purpose using a reactive approach. I'm hoping there's an elegant solution out there...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Emit the value once to add it, and emit it a second time to remove it. If you emit a third time it will be added back agan.

```
const uploadPicture = new Subject<UploadPicture>();

this.previewPictures$ = uploadPicture.pipe(
    scan<<UploadPicture, UploadPicture[]>(
      (pictures, newPicture) => pictures.includes(newPicture) ? pictures.filter(p=>p !== newPicture) : [...pictures, newPicture],
      []
    )
);

const pic = new UploadPicture();
this.uploadPicture.next(pic); // this will add the picture
this.uploadPicture.next(pic); // this will remove the picture
```

This can be done easily in the template.

```
<div *ngFor="let pic of previewPictures$ | async">
    <button (click)="uploadPicture.next(pic)">Remove</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @O.MeeKoh yeah, I've had problems like this before with `scan()`. Sometimes you have to set the generic arguments. I've updated the example if this helps.

Comment: wow that actually helped and fixed the underlying issue! Thank you so much!

Comment: At first I didn't like this solution because it seems "hacky", but the more I think about it, the more I like it. Very impressive!

Answer (score 1):

So we started by having a way to 'add' to the accumulation, and now we want some way to 'remove' from the accumulation. The key is to view these verbs ('add'/'remove') as what the items in the Observable really represent, rather than the noun ('picture'). Our existing `Subject<UploadPicture>` is a source of 'add' items. We could either change it to generalize over the verbs we care about, eg `Subject<PictureAction>`, or use an additional `Subject<RemovePicture>` to represent the new verb. I'll show what the latter could look like.

```
const uploadPicture = new Subject<UploadPicture>()
const removePicture = new Subject<RemovePicture>()

const previewPictures$ = merge(
    uploadPicture,
    removePicture,
).pipe(
    scan(
        (pictures, action) => {
            switch (action.type) {
                case 'add':    return [...pictures, action.picture],
                case 'remove': return pictures.filter(picture => picture.id !== action.pictureId)
            }
        },
        []
    )
)

const id = 78
const picture = new Picture(id)
uploadPicture.next(new UploadPicture(picture)) // Add the picture
removePicture.next(new RemovePicture(id))      // Remove the picture
```

In this example, `UploadPicture` and `RemovePicture` are assumed to have a `.type` field in common, so that we can tell which one we're dealing with. The `switch` inside the `scan` is conceptually a state machine, which specifies how events (our verbs) should affect the state (our accumulation). This generalizes if we ever need more verbs besides 'add' and 'remove'. Using multiple Subjects and `merge`-ing them allows us to easily consolidate events that could be coming from various places.